# Display three models in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models grandparent, parents, and childreen that i all would like to display on one site, like this:

```
Grandparents.name

  Parents.name ....

    Childreen.name ...
```

In the models i have:

**Grandparent**

```
has_many :parents
```

**Parent**

```
has_many :childreen
belongs_to :grandparents
```

**Childreen**

```
belongs_to :parents
```

So that i tried to generate an view like this:

```
<% @grandparents.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.name %>
  <%= f.Parent.find(params[f.id]).each do |s| %>
     <%= s.name %>
     </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But somehow i get the error:

```
 Undefined Method 'Parent' for #<Grandparent:02243x>
```

So what can i do or how would you display all generations in one view?

Actuall controller:

```
def index
@grandparents = Grandparent.all
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `grandparent` has many `parents`, you could write the statement as follows:

```
<%= f.parents.each do |s| %>
```

This gives you all the parents for `f` grandparent.

Comment: Ok and in my controller?

Comment: What is `@grandparents` currently? you shouldn't need to change anything in the controller.

Comment: I added my controller to the controller